# unlock gnome-keyring on login

Tags: debian, pam, i3, gnome-keyring, xinit

Running debian testing, no display manager, i3 window manager.
`gnome-keyring` & `libpam-gnome-keyring` packages are installed. Added following 2 lines to end of /etc/pam.d/login:

```
auth       optional     pam_gnome_keyring.so
session    optional     pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

keyring is started by systemd @ `/etc/systemd/user/graphical-session-pre.target.wants/gnome-keyring-daemon.service`, but also tried replacing it from xinitrc:

```
eval $(/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --replace --components=gpg,pkcs11,secrets,ssh)
```

/var/log/auth.log has following from OS login:

```
Jun 26 00:35:39 p14s su[1409]: (to laur) root on none
Jun 26 00:35:39 p14s su[1409]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user laur(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 26 00:35:39 p14s systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user laur(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 26 00:35:39 p14s su[1409]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user laur
Jun 26 00:35:41 p14s su[1922]: (to laur) root on none
Jun 26 00:35:41 p14s su[1922]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user laur(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s su[1922]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user laur
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s su[2005]: (to laur) root on none
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s su[2005]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user laur(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s login[1174]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s login[1174]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s login[1174]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user laur(uid=1000) by LOGIN(uid=0)
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s systemd-logind[1003]: New session 2 of user laur.
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s login[1174]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring <----- this should be success, right?
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s su[2005]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user laur
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s su[2078]: (to laur) root on none
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s su[2078]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user laur(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 26 00:35:42 p14s su[2078]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user laur
Jun 26 00:35:45 p14s polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:2 (system bus name :1.81 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jun 26 00:35:46 p14s gnome-keyring-daemon[2026]: The Secret Service was already initialized
Jun 26 00:35:46 p14s gnome-keyring-daemon[3062]: discover_other_daemon: 1
Jun 26 00:35:48 p14s su[4284]: (to laur) root on none
Jun 26 00:35:48 p14s su[4284]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user laur(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 26 00:35:50 p14s su[4284]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user laur
Jun 26 00:35:50 p14s su[4365]: (to laur) root on none
Jun 26 00:35:50 p14s su[4365]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user laur(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Jun 26 00:35:50 p14s su[4365]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user laur
Jun 26 00:35:50 p14s su[4402]: (to laur) root on none
Jun 26 00:35:50 p14s su[4402]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user laur(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
```

Did also try deleting existing keyring(s), to be re-created. Keyring has same password as my user login.

Still no joy. How to approach this in 2022?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `--replace` with `--start` within `.xinitrc`?

Comment: @Stephan yes, but that does nothing, as it wouldn't replace the process started by systemd. Also just noticed, when keyring is started by systemd, then I cannot see the `Login` (or even the 'Passwords' subsection) keyring listed in seahorse; ie the area marked would be gone: https://i.imgur.com/IPSavEc.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I got it sorted. Don't have deep understanding of what's going on, but it has to do with dbus.
Problem is the way i3 was started from `~/.xinitrc`:

```
exec dbus-run-session i3
```

I'm guessing it causes keyring-daemon to be tied to different dbus session than i3 (and, by extension, most everything else in user space).
To overcome this, I'm now launching i3 from `~/.xsession` via systemd instead; note I've deleted ~/.xinitrc altogether.

```
$ cat ~/.xsession
systemctl --user import-environment
systemctl --user daemon-reload

# note we add the 'wait' flag, which disallows immediate exit, which in turn would stop X session right after it.
exec systemctl --user start --wait xsession.target
```

startx is started with no arguments: `exec startx`

Relevant systemd units:

```
$ tree -a ~/.config/systemd/user/
├── i3wm.service
├── xsession.target
└── xsession.target.requires
    └── i3wm.service -> ../i3wm.service
    
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/i3wm.service 
[Unit]
Description=i3 Window Manager
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/i3
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/systemctl --user stop graphical-session.target
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
RequiredBy=xsession.target

$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/xsession.target
[Unit]
Description=X session managed by systemd
BindsTo=graphical-session.target
```

Encrypted keyring now gets unlocked by PAM on login as expected.
Note those two lines added to `/etc/pam.d/login` as described in the question are still very much needed.

Courtesy of [this blog](https://goral.net.pl/post/systemd-x-sessions/)